# Is there a way to import TS vars file in serverless.yml?

Tags: serverless-framework

I have a huge config object nicely typed in a TS file, and I wanna reuse it within the rest of my app. I also need to pass it to serverless. But serverless only supports js files, and I don’t wanna lose the config type information.

So, inside my `serverless.yml`:

```
${file(./config.js)}
```

would ideally be something like

```
${file(ts!./config.ts)}
```